# In the iOS API Reference, what does "receiver" mean?

Tags: ios, theory

I've been able to make sense of and use the API Reference fairly consistently so far, but the one thing that really irks me is that every time I run into this term, I basically have to ignore the definition in which it's used and figure out how the method/property in question works by applying it in code.

So can anyone clarify this matter for me?

**When the iOS API Reference mentions a "receiver" (and it does this a lot), what is that term referring to?**

Example of such a method description:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622442-convert

> Converts a point from the receiver’s coordinate system to that of the specified view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The receiver is the object on which a method is being invoked. For example, in this code:

```
let myView = UIView()
myView.convert(point, to: otherView)
```

The receiver of the `convert(_:to:)` method is `myView`.

This terminology comes from SmallTalk and Objective-C, where methods are called "messages" that you "send" to objects, and your objects "receive" them.

Comment: Well explained.